# Knockout.js bind to dynamically generated dialog

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to bind an observable object to a form loaded from the server. I can see the data on the javascript side but I can't see it on the HTML side, why?

Here is my client asking for the form:

```
self.showEntryDialog = function (elementId, title, partialViewName, verb, errorMessage) {
    var response = null;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/ServeView/",
        data: { partialView: partialViewName },
        async: false,
        success: function (text) {
            response = text;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            $("#errorPane").append(errorMessage + ": " + xhr.status + " " + error);
        }
    });
```

Here is the server passing a partial view:

```
public ActionResult ServeView(string partialView)
    {
        return PartialView(partialView);
    }
```

Once the view is loaded, it appends it to a dialog to-be:

```
if (response != null) {
        $("#" + elementId).dialog("destroy");

        $("#" + elementId).html(response);

        $("#" + elementId).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            modal: true,
            title: title,
            buttons: [
```

This is the HTML from the server that will be loaded into the dialog:

```
<!-- ko with: chosenDetailData -->
<form>
    <label for="txtID">ID:</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" id="txtID" data-bind="value: ID" disabled /><br />
    <label for="txtTableID">Table ID:</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" data-bind="value: TableID" id="txtTableID" /><br />
    <label for="txtColumnID">Column ID:</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" data-bind="value: ColumnID" id="txtColumnID" />
</form>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Here's where chosenDetailData is set:

```
<tr data-bind="click: function () {
            $root.chosenDetailData(new MultilingualViewModel($data.ID, $data.TableID, $data.ColumnID));
            $root.showEntryDialog('EntryDialog',
                'Edit table for multilingual support', '_EditMultilingual', 'PUT', 'Unable to load the view');
        }">
```

"chosenDetailData" is an observable property of my main view model. The main view model is bound earlier and the other observables work fine.

This is "MultilingualViewModel":

```
function MultilingualViewModel(id, tableId, columnId) {
var self = this;

self.ID = id;
self.TableID = tableId;
self.ColumnID = columnId;
}
```

When I check self.chosenDetailData prior to submitting my information to the server, I can see my data but it won't display on the form received from the server. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call applyBinding for your new HTML.

```
ko.applyBindings(yourViewModel.chosenDetailData(), document.getElementById("newHtmlId"));
```

Comment: Thank you but I had tried that and got "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element." Here's my code:

`ko.applyBindings($root.chosenDetailData(), document.getElementById('EntryDialog'));`

Comment: It  happens if your "EntryDialog" allready have a "data-bind" attribut on it. You can applyBinding on a child of it if you can't remove binding from it.